# MongoDB Sort subdocuments and subdocuments-of-subdocument while extracting document

Tags: mongodb

I need to extract data from `mongodb` force sorting subdocument based on its field.
I have a collection named `entries`. Each `entry` represents a `TvShow`, with its `Seasons` and its `Episodes`. Each `episode` has its `Mediafile`.
Just and example:

```
db.entries.findOne({})
{
     Title: "The Big Band Theory"
     Year: 2007,
     Seasons: [{
          Reorder: 2,
          Episodes: [{
               Reorder: 2,
               Mediafiles: [{
                    Reorder: 2
                    filename: "/tvshows/XXXXXX/S2_E2.mkv"
                }, {
                    Reorder: 1
                    filename: "/tvshows/XXXXXX/S2_E2.mkv"
                }
               ]
           }, {
               Reorder: 1,
               Mediafiles: [{
                    Reorder: 2
                    filename: "/tvshows/XXXXXX/S2_E1.mkv"
                }, {
                    Reorder: 1
                    filename: "/tvshows/XXXXXX/S2_E1.mp4"
                }
               ]
           } 
          ]}, {
          Reorder: 1,
          Episodes: [{
               Reorder: 2,
               Mediafiles: [{
                    Reorder: 2
                    filename: "/tvshows/XXXXXX/S1_E2.mkv"
                }, {
                    Reorder: 1
                    filename: "/tvshows/XXXXXX/S1_E2.mkv"
                }
               ]
           }, {
               Reorder: 1,
               Mediafiles: [{
                    Reorder: 2
                    filename: "/tvshows/XXXXXX/S1_E1.mkv"
                }, {
                    Reorder: 1
                    filename: "/tvshows/XXXXXX/S1_E1.mp4"
                }
               ]
           } 
          ]}
     ]
}
```

So, I'd like to extract these data sorted by `Reorder` field in each 'Season' 'Episode' and '`Mediafile`.

I tried with `$sort` but `Seasons` `Episodes` and `Mediafiles` are still not-sorted. I think I should use `$unwind` and `$project` but I can't do it recursively for subdocuments-of-subdocument.

Please, any help?

Answer (score 0):

Sorting applies to documents. When you sort, you are going to get the top-level documents back in the specified sort order, but sorting is not going to reorder keys within individual documents which is what you seem to be trying to do.

If you only want embedded documents, lift them to top level via projection then apply sort on them.

If you truly want to reorder fields, this is more complicated.